# Notifications is not received in Android

Tags: android

I have a service which sends notifications every 2 minutes..

When the phone gets locked no new notifications are received and only when I unlock my phone I receive notifications )

Whether there is any way to change it..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best solution for running some task every 2 minutes is [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) And do not use wakelocks except you don't need to hold device in work mode (like mp3 player for example), because it will spend battery.

**UPDATE FOR ENYONE WHO TO LAZY FOR READING MANUAL**

For using AlarmManager you need broadcast receiver at first.

```
public class ExampleReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
    // this method will be called by AlarmManager. But be carefull it has timeout
    // if your task need more time, you should run thread from there with wakelocks
  }
}
```

Then you can set task to AlarmManager.

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity
{
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,ExampleReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
   am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+INTERVAL,pendingIntent);
  }
}
```

This example run task once after INTERVAL. And it will wakeup phone for this task. You can set repeating tasks due AlarmManager, or it possible better to set new task just from receiver

Comment: I made device to come out of sleep mode by using a mediaplayer and now I am able to receive notifications but the bigger problem is I am not able to launch a intent automatically at a particular time..

Comment: By mediaplayer O_o Did you read example of AlarmManager usage?

Comment: Henry it's working fine:) But the only problem is I need to find  code for checking the status of phone to find out whether it's is in sleep mode or not..

Comment: You can't check it in BroadcastReceiver because when it started - device is waked up. BTW, for what you need this information? May be it possible to solve your task in another way

Answer (score 2):

When phone is locked, the device goes to deep-sleep mode and it will not handle any wait/sleep timer related delays.

Try using AlarmManager instead for getting notification every 2 mins. Or may be hold WAKE LOCKS (though might result in battery drain and not recommended)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to accomplish your goal using the PowerManager API:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html

You can use this to wake the phone up briefly to handle your notification. Make sure you're familiar with how the PowerManager API works, though - it's easy to write your code in a way that drains the battery.

Comment: this solution is quite bad. You will spend device battery. AlarmManager is better for repeating tasks

Comment: After re-reading the question, I agree - Henry's answer is better. Unless you're trying to keep the phone from going to sleep in the first place (which you probably shouldn't do).

Comment: In fact broadcast receiver which will work with AlarmManager has timeout, so if your task requires long amount of time you should start Thread from Receiver and use WakeLock while this thread is starting and works. But it is not necessary if you only set notification